# Is it possible to calculate the cdf of this r.v.?

Tags: probability

$X$ and $Y$ are two r.v.'s with cdfs $F_{X}$ and $F_{Y}$ respectively. $Z$ is another r.v. defined as $Z=X$ with probability $a$ and $Z=Y$ with probability $1-a$ and $P(X=Y)=0$. Then can we represent the cdf of $Z$ using $F_{X}$, $F_{Y}$ and $a$?

Comment: Have you tried anything at all? Start with $P(Z \le z)$, then condition on whether your biased coin flip is heads (with prob. $a$) or tails. This is almost a one-line proof.

Comment: I tried as: $P(Z \leq z) = P(Z \leq z, Z=X) + P(Z \leq z, Z=Y) = P(X \leq z, Z=X) + P(Y \leq z, Z=Y) $ then i do not know how to proceed. Could you explain more how to use conditioning?

Answer (score 0):

$$\begin{align*}
F_Z(z)
&=P(Z\leq z)\\\\
&=a\cdot P(X\leq z)+(1-a)\cdot P(Y\leq z)\\\\
&=a\cdot F_X(z)+(1-a)\cdot F_Y(z)\\\\
\end{align*}$$

Comment: Thanks. Could you explain how do you get the second "="?

Comment: We are given the probability that $Z=X$ is $a$ and the probability that $Z=Y$ is $1-a$. I would think of it as a weighted average.

Comment: Still do not understand. Could you give more rigorous reasoning or proof?

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you write

> $$ \Pr (Z \le z) = \Pr ( Z\le z, Z= X) + \Pr (Z \le z, Z=Y). $$

Notice that

\begin{align*}
\Pr(Z \le z, Z=X) &= \Pr (X \le z, Z = X) \\
&= \Pr (X \le z) \cdot \Pr(Z=X) \\
&= a F_X (z).
\end{align*}

Now do the same for the term involving $Y$.

Comment: Strictly speaking all the answers I see till now make an extra assumption of independence. (eg. second line in the answer by Theoretical Econimist). The correct answer is that the distribution of $Z$ cannot be expressed in terms of those of $X$ and $Y$ and the variable $a$ in general.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Isn’t the assumption of independence implicit in the definition of $Z$?

Comment: Well, it depends where the OP encountered this question. In an advanced course independence assumptions have to be stated precisely.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy Can you give an example of (distinct) random variables $X$ and $Y$ such that I can construct $Z$ in the way described (that is, $Z=X$ with probability $a$, and $Z=Y$ otherwise) where the independence assumption would not hold?

Comment: How about this: $Y=2X$. Then $X$ and $Y$ are not independent. So  $P(X \leq z, Z=X) \neq P(X \leq z) \cdot P(Z=X) $?

Comment: @Peter $X$ and $Y$ do not have to be independent for the events $\{X\le z\}$ and $\{Z=X\}$ to be independent.